# Confused on how to input three lines each stored as a string

Tags: python

I need to define a variable called joined_with_commas that holds a string with the contents of s1, followed by a comma, followed by s2, followed by a comma, followed by s3. Im not sure how to go about this.
I have this so far

```
>>>joined_with_commas = "s1, + s2, + s3"
```

Please help!!

Comment: `joined_with_commas = s1 + ', ' + s2 + ', ' + s3` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s1="string1"
s2="string2"
s3="string3"

joined_with_commas = s1+ ", "+ s2+ ", "+ s3
```

here it is, you gotta use the + operator to merge strings in a variable

Answer (score 2):

Python has many ways do this. Any of the following will work

```
joined_with_commas = s1 + ', ' + s2 + ', ' + s3
joined_with_commas = ', '.join((s1, s2, s3))
joined_with_commas = '{}, {}, {}'.format(s1, s2, s3)
joined_with_commas = f'{s1}, {s2}, {s3}'
```